# having difficulty compiling this file I have one error but I am not sure what to do

Tags: java

```
// DrawPanelTest.java                             
// Application to display a DrawPanel.
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawPanelTest {

public static void main( String[] args ) {


// create a panel that contians our drawing
DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
// create a new frame to hold the panel
JFrame application = new JFrame();

// set the frame to exit when it is close
   application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    application.add( panel ); // add the panel to the frame
    application.setSize( 250, 250 ); // set tje size of the frame
    application.setVisible( true ); // make the frame visible
 } // end main\
} // end class DrawPanelTest


import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
 //int for whole class
 private int N;

 // constructor
 public DrawPanel(int numLines)
 {
     N = numLines;
 } // end constructor

   // draws an numLines from the corners of the panel
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
     // call paintComponent to ensurethe angle displays
     super.paintComponent(g);

     int width = getWidth(); // total width
     int height = getHeight(); // total height

     // draws (N + 1) lines with equal spacing
     if (N > 0) {
         for (int counter = 0; counter <= N; counter++) {
             g.drawLine(0, height / 2, width, counter * height / N);

         }
     }
 }
```

}
having difficulty with an error and not sure what to do or how to approach the error need help thanks

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1006]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\MAC>cd desktop

C:\Users\MAC\Desktop>javac DrawPanel.java

C:\Users\MAC\Desktop>javac DrawPanelTest.java
DrawPanelTest.java:11: error: constructor DrawPanel in class DrawPanel cannot be applied to given types;
     DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
                       ^
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

C:\Users\MAC\Desktop>

Comment: please post your DrawPanel class

Comment: ok thanks just did

Answer (score 1):

Either create a no parameter constructor or pass a parameter while calling class like below:-

```
 public DrawPanel()
 {
     N = 1;// if you want to assign some default value
 }
```

Run with parameter like below:-

```
javac Arguments.java
java Arguments arg0 arg1 arg2
```